# Calling JavaScript typeof as operator vs function

Tags: javascript, typeof

I've seen `typeof` being called as an unary operator and as what it looks like a function:

```js
typeof "bla"  // like a unary operator
typeof("bla") // like a function
```

But is it really being called as a function or it's just an expression that looks like a function call? Like this:

```js
typeof ("a string surrounded by parens")
```

I looked at the spec and it seems it's just an unary operator. But I'm not good reading the spec.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#unary_operators

Comment: The grouping operator can be put around any expression. So yeah, it can make any unary operator look like a function call: `delete(foo.bar)`, `-(baz)`.

Comment: And that is the reason why many style guides recommend to always follow keywords with a space, even `if`, `for`, `while`, `function`... So you never think of them as function calls.

Comment: @Domino yeah, i think prettier auto adds the space and removes the parens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one

```
typeof("bla")
```

it is the [grouping operator `()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping), not part of a function call.

Comment: Thought so. It would be interesting to prove it's an unary operator. Suppose I'll have to trust the spec.

Comment: @ArturCarvalho `typeof (typeof)` vs `typeof (_=>_)` or `typeof (Math.random)`.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz yeah, it's sort of proof by exclusion because there is no "operator" type.

Comment: @ArturCarvalho Right. Also, if it were a function, it would be available in `global` on Node or `window` on browser, like `setTimeout`.